# Iterating over pandas rows, looking for a specific number and counting how many times we encountered it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

beginner in Python here.

I have a very simple dataframe that's filled with 0's and 1's. Every row looks a bit like this:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0

My end goal is to iterate through every row, and where there is a 1 in a cell to check if there is another 1 after it (so if there are consecutive 1's to just count them as one event). So for example in this row above, the two 1's will be counted as 1 event (in an integer that's keeping store, or a list, it doesn't really matter).

I've decided to write a function findEvents and then pass it to df.apply (in order to perform it to every row of the df), but I'm struggling with the findEvents function itself. So what I have so far is this, however it doesn't have the ability to check for consecutive 1's and also it gives the following error - TypeError: ("findEvents() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'", 'occurred at index 0')

```
def findEvents(df, row):
eventsCounter = 0
for i in row:
        if i == 1:
            eventsCounter = eventsCounter + 1
            print(eventsCounter)
        
        else:
            return eventsCounter
```

df.apply(findEvents, axis=1)

Any suggestions on the TypeError and/or how to modify the function so it counts consecutive 1's are welcome!

Comment: Can you have three consecutive ones, like this: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0?  If so, what is the expected result?

Comment: yeah what if you have 4 in a row; is that 2 events? Need more background here/

Comment: Regardless of how many consecutive 1's it would still be counted as one 'event'. So the event would stop when there's a 0 again, is this making more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the the rows that have consecutive ones in them by iterating over the entire dataset like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'c2': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'c3': [0, 1, 0, 1], 'c4': [1, 0, 0, 1], 'c5': [0, 1, 0, 0]})

for row_idx, row in df.iterrows():
    previous = 0
    for item_idx, item in row.iteritems():
        if item == 1 and item == previous:
            print(row_idx)
            // do something with the row
            break
        previous = item
```

This will iterate over the rows of the dataset and then iterate over the columns (or in this case it will be a series so just an array) and if their are any consecutive 1's (if the current item is a 1 and equal to the previous value) then do something with the row and break as their isn't any need to do anything else with the row